# Handling jquery event with casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a web page where after the dom is loaded javascript continues to run on the page and adds elements onto the page. After all the javascript is run I fire a jquery event page.loaded  so that components on the page that are interested in doing something after all my javascripts are run can do so.

I am trying to automate the testing of this webpage using casperjs/phantomjs and I would like to examine elements on the page only after the jQuery page loaded event is fired. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Time for a feedback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [waitFor](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.waitFor) family functions in order to wait for something to happen in the page environment. You can either wait for [some element](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.waitForSelector) or [text](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.waitForText) to be available in the DOM, or directly add a specific jQuery listener in order to process further steps:

```
casper.start('test.html', function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        $(document).on('site:loaded', function() {
            window.siteLoaded = true;
        });
    });
});

casper.waitFor(function() {
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        return window.siteLoaded === true;
    });
});

casper.then(function() {
    // process further
});
```

**Note:** this is factice pseudo code, purpose is only to picture the concept.